# Powershell - NewItemUnauthorizedAccessError

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, prtg

I receive the following error when using the `New-Item` cmdlet to create backup copies of files:

`new-item : Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PRTG Network Monitor\webroot\mailtemplates' is denied.
At line:1 char:21
+ foreach ($i in $a) {new-item  -itemtype file -name $i.bak}
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Program File...t\mailtemplates:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAcc
   essException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand`

Here is the command I am executing:

`pwd

C:\Program Files (x86)\PRTG Network Monitor\webroot\mailtemplates

$a = ls

foreach ($i in $a) {new-item  -itemtype file -name $i.bak}`

- I am logged on as the local Administrator
- Administrator is member of Administrators Group
- Administrators Group has full permissions on that folder
- I started the POSH console as Administrator
- Execution Policy is set to remote signed (just in case it matters)
- I can use the `New-Item` cmdlet to create a test.txt file within that folder
- I can use the GUI to create copies of all files within that directory

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach ($i in $a) {new-item  -itemtype file -name "$($i.basename).bak"}
```

Comment: Here's what I get:   `foreach ($i in $a) {new-item -itemtype file -name "$($i.htm).txt"}  
  
-a---         3/26/2014   8:17 AM          0 .txt  
new-item : The file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PRTG Network Monitor\webroot\mailtemplates\.txt' already exists.
At line:1 char:21
+ foreach ($i in $a) {new-item -itemtype file -name "$($i.htm).txt"}
+                     
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Program File...ltemplates\.txt:String) [New-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand`

Comment: Worked as advertised. Not familiar with the syntax. I misunderstood what you meant by basename. Thank you.

Comment: @kira Ok. basename is a property of a [fileinfo] object. the sintax `$($variablename.properties)` is neeeded whan you need to expand in a string the property value of a variable.